# Don't understand how {component: Component} in a React PrivateRoute works

Tags: jsx, react-router-dom

See the classic PrivateRoute contstruction below:

```
<Switch>
        <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path='/signup' component={Signup} />
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
</Switch>
```

and then

```
export default function PrivateRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth();
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
                return currentUser ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                    <Redirect to='/login' />
                );
            }}
        ></Route>
    );
}
```

I am trying to understand the syntax `{component: Component}`. I have read the following in https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/react-router-explanation/178787/2:

> If I’m not mistaken, the reason that the component prop is reassigned to the Component identifier is because the JSX  attempts to create a component DOM element (which doesn’t exist) instead of a React component—a capitalised identifier is required for creating a React component.

But I still don't get how the component passed as `component` is transformed into the capitalized version, `Component`. This seems to go beyond vanilla JS syntax (into JSX?) and I don't get it.

Thanks!

Comment: it is vanilla JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names

Comment: Thanks, @azium !